# Get IMEI number with ADB command

Tags: adb, 7.0-nougat, imei

I am working with ADB on my Samsung Galaxy device. I want to get the IMEI number of the device using ADB, but I have been unable to do that.

I tried the following:

```
adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
```

but it returns nothing.

I also tried with Service Call Command:

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo
```

but it gives me a strange result like this:

```
Result: Parcel(                                                        
0x00000000: 00000000 0000000f 00350033 00390038 '........3.5.8.9.'    
0x00000010: 00320037 00380030 00350034 00350031 '7.2.0.8.4.5.1.5.'   
0x00000020: 00300031 00000033                   '1.0.3...        ')
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: You could try  calling an intent like below: 

    am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d "tel:*%2306%23"

Comment: @esQmo_ But that will just open Dialer wirh IMEI getting code. I don't user to manually do anything.

Comment: Related: [How to get 2nd IMEI number using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219102/218526)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this code in to a .bat file and running it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=6*" %%a in ('adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 ^| grep -m 1 \"'\""') do (
set imei1=%%a)
for /f "tokens=6*" %%b in ('adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 ^| grep -m 2 \"'\""') do (
set imei2=%%b)
for /f "tokens=4*" %%c in ('adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 ^| grep -m 3 \"'\""') do (
set imei3=%%c) 
set imei=!imei1!!imei2!!imei3!
echo !imei! > imei.txt
for /f "delims=" %%d in (imei.txt) do (
set DeviceIMEI=%%d
set DeviceIMEI=!DeviceIMEI:'=!
set DeviceIMEI=!DeviceIMEI:.=!
set OIMEI=Phone IMEI  !DeviceIMEI!
)
echo %OIMEI%
pause
```

I got it from this StackOverflow thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34362809/8173870

Answer (score 8):

Given the tag [7.0-nougat](/questions/tagged/7.0-nougat), I'm assuming you have or are targeting Android Nougat. Android Nougat comes with *toybox* which acts as an alternative to busybox and has some useful utilities. I managed to use those tools to print IMEI like this:

```
adb shell
service call iphonesubinfo 1 | toybox cut -d "'" -f2 | toybox grep -Eo '[0-9]' | toybox xargs | toybox sed 's/\ //g'
```

Since you wouldn't be getting an interactive shell when using a script or an app, you can pass the commands like this:

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 | toybox cut -d \"'\" -f2 | toybox grep -Eo '[0-9]' | toybox xargs | toybox sed 's/\ //g'"
```

Answer (score 4):

The following ADB command works on my Windows PC to get clear IMEI result:

`adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 4 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"`

Comment: thanks for sharing the best code. I get IMEI result by this code, but it's only show 1st IMEI.
If I want to get result 2nd IMEI what should we put the code ? thanks for Answers.

Comment: I changed the code from `iphonesubinfo 1` to `iphonesubinfo 4`, which is the correct service code to get the **full** IMEI.
So try: `adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 4 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"`, and see if you get also IMEI 2.

Answer (score 2):

`adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo` works only for phones below Android 5 Lolipop.

Because Android Nougat is over 5.0, you need: `adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=`

Comment: i am using Windows as OS so it gives me Error awk not found. What would be Equivalent of awk in windows Command Prompt?

Comment: There is no equivalent to awk on Windows. But you can simply install all the *nix tools also on Windows. A very simple way to do that is [`scoop`](http://scoop.sh/). Or you have to create a windows tool that parses the command-line result without those tools.

Answer (score 2):

Using [android-svc](https://github.com/T-vK/android-svc/):

```
android-svc --adb call 'iphonesubinfo.getDeviceId();'
```

would return something like this:

```
358972084515103
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not have realized it, but you've actually posted the answer to your own question:

```
  Result: Parcel(                                                        
0x00000000: 00000000 0000000f 00350033 00390038 '........3.5.8.9.'    
0x00000010: 00320037 00380030 00350034 00350031 '7.2.0.8.4.5.1.5.'   
0x00000020: 00300031 00000033                   '1.0.3...        ')
```

Specifically, the portion to the right:

```
'........3.5.8.9.'
'7.2.0.8.4.5.1.5.'         
'1.0.3...        '
```

Simply put it all on one line and remove the single quotes and it becomes:

`........3.5.8.9.7.2.0.8.4.5.1.5.1.0.3...`

Now remove the dots and you get:

```
358972084515103
```

(aka your IMEI number)

Answer (score 2):

##### esim imei is available via:

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL;
sleep 1;
input text '*#06#'; 
uiautomator dump --compressed /dev/stdout\
    |tr ' ' '\n'\
    |awk -F'"' '{print $2}'|grep "^[0-9]\{15\}$" \
    |nl -w 1 -s':'\
    |sed 's/^/IMEI/g'
```

```
IMEI1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx
IMEI2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```